# Iterating through alien list

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency

Lets say I have a list returned by an arbitrary method:

```
List<E> someList = someObject.getList();
```

`someList` can be changed at any time by `someObject` in another thread. I have no access to the implementation of `someObject`, and `someObject.getList()` does not return a synchronized or immutable list implementation.

I want to iterate through `someList`. Unfortunately, since the list can be changed, iterating through it normally doesn't work:

```
// Sometimes throws ConcurrentModificationException
for(E element : someObject.getList()) {
    doSomething(element);
    // ...
}
```

So how can I iterate through a list (not thread safe) returned by an alien method?

Comment: Maybe create a copy?

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html

Comment: @Christian During copy i.e. using ArrayList.clone() or so, if the list is being modified, won't he get a wrong copy?

Comment: @GentiSaliu I don't think that helps... it doesn't mention concurrency.

Comment: @radoh But that relies on the backend list not being modified without proper thread safety

Comment: @radoh That won't work.  At all.  Synchronization requires cooperation from both sides.  Plus, it won't prevent a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @Christian Isn't copying the list iterating anyway?

Comment: You can also synchronize both the method/statements you iterate the list and the methods/statements which modify it.

Comment: @GentiSaliu That's the problem, I don't have access to the methods that modify the list whilst I'm iterating, and they can occur whilst I'm iterating.

Comment: Synchronize the call to those methods maybe?

Comment: @GentiSaliu It's an alien method. I don't modify the list, ever. Those methods are part of an API I'm using. I don't have access to them.

Comment: Probably iterate in a synchronized block like : synchronized( aMonitor ) { while( it.hasNext() ) ..Also you shouldn't be doing getList() in your for loop it is calling getList() everytime loop is iterated.

Comment: @svasa but I can't control the API modifying the list without synchronization. The API changes the list, I only iterate through it.

Comment: I am not saying modify the list. Just iterate the list you got under a synchronized block.

Comment: Try [locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html). If your thread has acquired the lock, the list can't be changed. Release lock when you are done iterating. [List of available lock mechanisms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html), see especially [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Comment: @GentiSaliu Locking must be co-operative, the different threads accessing the code must all use the same lock. The API doesn't use any synchronization.

Comment: Try making the list immutable with `final List<E> someList = someObject.getList();`, iterate through it, and then poll periodically for changes.

Comment: "Poll periodically for changes" - how do you propose to do that? What would happen if there was a change? Isn't this quite a "hacky" method?

Comment: I don't know what options there are with the API you are using, as `someObject.getList` is not thread safe. One way is to setup a timer and do `final List<E> someList = someObject.getList();` every time - you can also try comparing new and old list and iterate on it if there have been changes. It is a bit "hacky", but I can't think of a better solution at the moment.

Comment: Vlad Dinulescu's last suggestion is not bad. You could write a wrapper for `ArrayList` (i.e. `ThreadUnsafeArrayList`), which holds off access as long as `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown. Timers would be involved here as well.

Comment: Also, [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#CopyOnWriteArrayList(java.util.Collection)) seems very promising, it is thread safe and does not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the other thread uses a synchronization mechanism like synchronized(list) for modifying the list; in that case you could use synchronized on the same object and you'd be safe.

```
List<E> list=someobject.getList();
synchronized (list) {
   for (E element : list) {
        doSomething(element);
   }
}
```

You can try synchronizing on the list or on someObject and hope it works.

Other than that, I don't see any clean solution. 
In the end, if the other code that modifies the list doesn't care about other users of the list, it's pretty impossible to iterate safely.

Unclean one: try to copy the array in a loop until the ConcurrentModificationException is not thrown anymore.

Comment: The thing is, my iteration happens to be part of the application's networking which wouldn't work very well with potentially infinite delays. I guess I'll just have to see if there are any workarounds :/